# What does "people whose tags of you" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Looking at Google+ settings I have found the following sentence:

> People whose tags of you are automatically approved to link to your Profile

I don't understand how to parse the sentence, since "whose tags" should be referred to *people* but then there is "of you." It is not clear what the subject of the sentence is: Who or what is automatically approved?

> [image: screenshot]

As English learner, should I use such construction in sentences I write?

Comment: I have to say that is a very oddly written sentence. I get what it means now, but it took a minute and I had to read the answers to confirm (admittedly I'm not familiar with G+). They might have written it more clearly as: "Tags of you are automatically approved to link to your Profile when made by these people:". Though that's wordy as well. I definitely think the original is awkward phrasing, there has to have been a better way to write that. "Tags of you" is awkward in itself, but I'm not familiar enough with G+ to invent another phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "people whose tags of you" sentence refers to people who have created tags of you / have tagged you. What will be approved is tags of you by the people in the list of circles you are asked to create.

"of you" is used to specify that not *all* tags those people create will be automatically approved for your profile, only the tags... of you ;)

Comment: Could that be rephrase as "people who create tags about you"? I am assuming that it's _people_ to be allowed to link to my profile; otherwise I would use "tags created by people who tag you."

Comment: @kiamlaluno It's the people that you approve, but the list you are creating is essentially a list of tags (of you) that will be automatically linked to in your profile. The links are automatic, the people in the list will not manually add links to your profile (they might, but that's not what this list is about). When they tag you, those tags will appear in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

It means that when some people tag you (that will be their tags of you), these tags are automatically linked to your profile; you do not need to approve. What follows that phrase is a list of those people.